# Mathematics behind simultaneous 3d rotations

Tags: geometry, 3d, rotations

I'm trying to simulate the effect of two simultaneous rotations acting on a sphere, more specifically: rotation and precession of the earth. These two rotations act on different rates and different axes simultaneously on the celestial sphere.
¿Where can I read a good mathematical treatment about this topic?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html an easy place to start. Solid body rotations are especially common in physics so you can look through those forums as well.

Comment: Thanks @Mark for your rapid response. I already know how a 3d rotation can be represented by a 3x3 matrix, and the use of quaternions in this topic. But I haven't found where to look for the following question. Given a rotation by angle a and axis u, and a rotation by angle b and rotation v, how can I obtain the angle c and axis w that is equivalent to the result of combining **simultaneously** the two given rotations.

Comment: Model the orientation of the sphere instead, as a function of time.  You'll find that precession is just the time-dependent change in the orientation of the primary rotation axis.  You can even model the changes in precession over time with this approach.